# Are there certain reference frames where proper length of proper time are supposed to be measured?

Tags: special-relativity

Let's say we have two frames: Bob on Earth and Alice in a rocketship. Let's say Alice is traveling at a relativistic speed away from Bob. With that in mind. Is there a certain frame where we should measure the proper length of the rocket? Does the same apply when finding the proper time of rocket? Also, I don't necessarily mean FIND in the sense that it is unknown. What I mean is in which frame do we consider the length or time to be proper, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you define proper?  Perhaps starting with a non-relativistic example?  Say measuring the speed of a train from the prospective of a passenger and observer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember this in mind when dealing with special relativity: there is not a "better reference"

If they are all frames in constant velocity,say Bob and Alice in your question. You can't distinguish them apart from "any" physical experiment.
They are theoretically the same(and indeed they are!!

What you are wondering is that "which reference" are you care
Both Bob and Alice have their "own" proper time and proper length,or even proper energy as you wish.
The thing only matter is not "definitely" proper length,but a "relativistically" proper length depend on your frame.
So there is a proper length for Bob and another proper length for Alice, only depend on which frame you choose.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I'm taking a modern physics course and some of the examples and questions we have come across made it seem as though there was a certain frame that had special properties, but that was my misinterpretation. Thank you.